# 18.04: Brave/Chrome exit suddenly

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome

So I am using Brave and Chrome browser, but both browser often quit suddenly (crashing) with no warning signs. I tried to reinstall the browser but it didn't help. Is there a problem with the browser?

I don't know how to post the log for this or where to find the log. Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks.

Brave: Version 1.2.43 Chromium: 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Chrome: Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You can see the log if you start the browser from Terminal.

Comment: `[4333:4344:0204/124203.121153:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(990)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.`

Comment: I am using external 2080 super with `nvidia-driver-440` and cuda 10.2, if it helps

Comment: or probably it's an issue with ESET I'm using, after a google search...